# Sumif partial data in a column meets a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a sum of G3:G47 if A54 matches the first 3 characters in the cell range A3:A47

[image: Exmaple 1]

[image: Example 2]

This is the formula I have been trying to tinker with, but it doesn't work.

```
=SUMIF(A$3:A$47,LEFT(A$3:A$47,3)=[@[Sprint ID]],C$3:C$47)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WildCards:

```
=SUMIF(A$3:A$47,[@[Sprint ID]] & "*",C$3:C$47)
```